# Include angular-touch in JHipster

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

I am trying to include angular-touch into my JHipster Application. Therfore I made the following steps:

1. I installed angular-touch with bower. I used the command "bower install angular-touch".
2. Then I included the angular-touch js file inside the head of my index.html like this

   script src="/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"/>
3. Then I included the angular touch inside my app.js like this 
   angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch']);

I am always getting an Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

What am I doing wrong? I think that the script is not included correctly. Where do I include a script in my jHipster Application?

Comment: Have you checked the browser's Javascript console to see that angular-touch.js is being loaded and is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I have checked. The module was not loaded. The problem was that I have included the script inside the head at the top of my page and not at the bootom. When I included the page at the bottom with the other scripts everything worked perfectly fine.